# NodeJS - File Write/Http request truly asychronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, asynchronous, synchronous

Im running the following typescript file with node:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

let Discord = require('discord.js');
let Hook = new Discord.WebhookClient('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx');

Hook.send("hello")

for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
```

The send call is asynchronous, however the Hook is actually sent **after** the last iteration of the loop. This is the same when i replace the http code with `fs.writeFile("result.txt", "Hey there!", function(err) {console.log("The file was saved!");});`

How can i achieve that the function is called truly asynchronous or even synchronously. I just want the http request be sent before the execution of the whole loop.

Comment: it is truly asynchronous - read about javascript [Concurrency and event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) to understand why your code behaves as it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hook.send` will be executed synchronously, but if it interacts with the network then it will also perform some blocking work that will be added to the event loop.

The event loop will only be processed once the thread has finished executing the synchronous code. This is why the hook actually sends after the loop has run.

If you want to delay the loop until the asynchronous work has finished, then you need to wait for the promise (that [`Hook.send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/WebhookClient?scrollTo=send) returns) to resolve.

As you're using TypeScript, you already have access to `async/await` regardless of the version of Node you're using, so it'd be possible to restructure your code.

```
async main() {
  await Hook.send("hello");

  // continue doing synchronous work
}

main().catch(err => throw err);
```

Comment: Thank you this solved the actual problem. Promises weren't appropriate since my code is not based on events

Comment: @Chocolate - You are a bit misguided if you think that Promises don't apply here.  They are useful for ANY asynchronous operation which `Hook.send()` is.  It has nothing to do with how else your code is structured.  Promises are one method of tracking completion and errors in asynchronous operations and coordinating them with other code which is exactly what you are trying to do here - so dismissing them the way you did in your comment makes it apparent that you don't understand their usefulness and how they would apply here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Promises`, we can use the `.then()` to wait until something is done. So that we can continue with our other executions:

```
let Discord = require('discord.js'); let Hook = new 
Discord.WebhookClient('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx');

Hook.send("hello").then(function(response) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
})
```

Comment: doesn't this **assume** that `Hook.send` returns a Promise?

Comment: It does https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/WebhookClient?scrollTo=send

Comment: Yes, if it isn't a Promise, we would have to make it one so that we can make this asynchronous. I had assumed `Discord .WebhookClient` was already a promise. Was it not?

Comment: in that case, carry on :p

Answer (score 0):

If you can have a callback function for your operations, you can nest callbacks.

E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

let Discord = require('discord.js');
let Hook = new Discord.WebhookClient('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx', function callback(err, res) {
    console.log('File saved or async operation finishes here');
    Hook.send("hello");
});
```

You can try t his with `fs.writeFile` first as you mentioned in your question. The crux here is that the callback function passed in named `callback`, is called when the async operation is finished. `Hook.send` is then called inside that function, to guarantee it's executed after the first function is finished.

Once you start doing this a lot, you'll run into something called a callback hell, where you'd have cases where lots of callbacks are nested.

You will want to check out [async module](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) or JS Promises and Promise chaining.